# SQL injection help

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

So I was just testing out the `mysql_real_escape();` function and what that does is puts a `\` before the `"`. The when the content is echoed back out onto the page I just get content with `\'`s before any `"`. So let's say I posted `""""""""""""""""""""""""""""` all I get is `\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"` echoed back.

Is there some code to remove the `\` when it's echoed back onto the page?

Comment: You use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when you're about to put strings into a database.  When you read the strings back out of the database, they will be unescaped.  Obviously, if you just do `echo mysql_real_escape_string($my_string));`, you will get the effect that you are seeing.

Comment: How are you inserting data to the database? If you are executing an INSERT query constructed by hand, then `mysql_real_escape_string()` is needed. If you are using prepared statements (passing values to be inserted as arguments), then not. Please paste a minimal code example that behaves incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

By adding those slashes, `mysql_real_escape_string` just converts the string into the input format for the database. When the data comes out of the database, it should come out without any of the slashes. You shouldn't need to remove them yourself.

Using `stripslashes` like others are suggesting would do the opposite of `mysql_real_escape_string` in most cases, but not all of them, and you shouldn't rely on it for that purpose. Mind you, if you find yourself needing to use it for this, you've already done something else wrong.

Comment: $text_share_body = $_POST['text_share_body'];
$text_share_body = mysql_real_escape_string($text_share_body);

Comment: it goes into the database with '\'s before the ' " 's but it doesn't automaticly undo the slashes on the output

Comment: @frankmeacey: If you need to display `$text_share_body` in the page, you shouldn't replace it with the escaped version. Put the escaped version in a new variable, and use that in your query, and keep the original value for displaying in the page.

Comment: $text_share_body = $_POST['text_share_body']; 
$escaped_text_share_body = mysql_real_escape_string($text_share_body);

Comment: I still get the slashes appearing on the page when the variable $text_share_body is echoed from the database

Comment: @frankmeacey: Are the slashes in the `$_POST` data as well? This might  be PHP's idiotic "magic quotes" feature screwing things up; PHP.net [has some code you can copy to disable this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: Thank you so much @Jeremy of the Banks just read it again and disabled the magic quotes thing and it is all working now!

Answer (score 1):

stripslashes()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to unescape, ie. remove the slashes - they don't get inserted into the DB. They are only for passing data to MySQL, they are not written to the db. When you `SELECT` the data, you won't see the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how `mysql_real_escape()` works. Hint: It allows to encode string for SQL usage. For example `mysql_query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name="'.mysql_real_escape_string($name).'"');`. It can be used to insert string which won't escape the quotes for example like `" or 1=1 -- "` making `SELECT * FROM users WHERE name="" or 1=1`. You have to activate it **just before** inserting it database.

When you will read this data, slashes won't exist in any way.

Actually, looking at what is below, I will make this answer, not comment...